# Can Django ORM has strip field?

Tags: python, django

When I query this:

```
signal = Data.objects.filter(signal = "aa:bb:cc")
```

I found a problem

My database has a signal value "aa:bb:cc " with a space at the end
So when it filter `signal = "aa:bb:cc"`  it got nothing
Does Django has method I can `strip` string first  ??

something like

```
signal = Data.objects.filter(signal__strip = "aa:bb:cc")
```

Comment: Would `signal__startswith` work in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

1) `.filter(signal__startswith='aa:bb:cc')` if that's suitable criteria, or, if you want to be more strict, then:

2) `.filter(signal__regex='^aa:bb:cc *$')` to match columns that start with the signal value and end purely with zero or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

No django doesn't provide such method but you can use [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) or [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#contains) instead

```
signal = Data.objects.filter(signal__icontains="aa:bb:cc")
```